# Google spreadsheet create a new sheet with permission for all users have link

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I tried to user the google sheet API v4 to create a new sheet. I create it successfully. However, I found that the sheet is setting as I am the only one is able to access. My goal is to allow users have the url link can access the sheet in Java request.

I tried to set google credidential to null when create spreadsheet, but it use as to create the spreadsheet in drive. Thus, this is not work.
I browser it library class and api, but I cannot found anything related to the permission.

I am not so sure the way I create the spreadsheet is on right way. Here is my code:

```
public class CreateSpreadSheetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets mService = null;
    private Exception mLastError = null;
    private String title = null;
    private CreateSpreadsheetListener listener = null;

    public CreateSpreadSheetTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential, String title, CreateSpreadsheetListener listener) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new Sheets.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Google Sheets API Android Quickstart")
                .build();
        this.title = title;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            this.listener.onRecvCreateSpreadsheet(getSpreadsheetFromApi());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mLastError = e;
            cancel(true);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Spreadsheet getSpreadsheetFromApi() throws IOException {
        Spreadsheet spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        SpreadsheetProperties properties = new SpreadsheetProperties();
        properties.setTitle(this.title);
        spreadsheet.setProperties(properties);
        Sheets.Spreadsheets.Create request = mService.spreadsheets().create(spreadsheet);
        return request.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the Drive REST API to share the document / make it public. The file id for Drive is the same as the `spreadsheetId` that the Sheets API gives you in the response from `Create`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tehhowch said the permission should handle via the Drive API. Here is just update an answer for this.

```
private void updateProperty(com.google.api.services.drive.Drive driveService, String fileId, String email) throws IOException {
    BatchRequest batch = driveService.batch();
    Permission clientPermission = new Permission();
    clientPermission.setEmailAddress(email);
    clientPermission.setRole("writer");
    clientPermission.setType("user");
    driveService.permissions().create(fileId, clientPermission)
            .setFields("id")
            .setSendNotificationEmail(true)
            .queue(batch, new JsonBatchCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Object o, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) throws IOException {
                    Log.e("permissione success", String.valueOf(o));
                    listener.onRecvShareSpreadsheet(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) throws IOException {
                    Log.e("permissione error", e.getMessage());
                    listener.onRecvShareSpreadsheet(false);
                }
            });
    batch.execute();
}
```

ref: [Google api permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions)